# Get param and element by strings

Tags: c#, properties, parameters, get

How realize this method in c#:

```
public static void SetParam(string element, string property, dynamic value){
 // Do something
}

// Usage:
setParam("textBox1","Text","Hello");
```

In JavaScript this looks:

```
function SetParam(element, property, value) {
 document.getElementById(element)[property]=value;
}

// Usage:
SetParam("textBox","value","Hello");
```

Comment: What is meaning of "element" in C# code?

Comment: If you know element and property when passing values to a separate method why can't you do `textbox1.Text = value;` in code-behind instead of calling separate method to set values.

Comment: I need set property values from method with three known strings: element (ElementID, such as texbox1), property (such as Text) and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the following works for you.

```
public void SetParam(string element, string property, dynamic value)
{
    FieldInfo field = typeof(Form1).GetField(element, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    object control = field.GetValue(this);
    control.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(control, value, null);
}
```

Replace `Form1` with the form class that contains the controls you want to modify.

Edit: After having read Blachshma's answer, I realize that you'll have to put

```
using System.Reflection;
```

at the top of the file.

I also assumed it's for a Windows Forms Application.

Lastly, a better way to get a reference to the control is probably to use the `Form.Controls` property like Greg suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this can be done with a little help of **[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)** ...

Start by adding a: `using System.Reflection;` to the top of your cs file.

Since I don't know if you're using WPF or Winforms - here are 2 examples...
WPF:

You can use this version of SetParam:

```
private void SetParam(string name, string property, dynamic value)
{
      // Find the object based on it's name
      object target = this.FindName(name);

      if (target != null)
      {
          // Find the correct property
          Type type = target.GetType();
          PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(property);

          // Change the value of the property
          prop.SetValue(target, value);
      }
}
```

Usage:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   SetParam("textbox", "Text", "Hello");
```

Where `textbox` is declared like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox" />
```

For Winforms just change SetParam to this:

```
private void SetParam(string name, string property, dynamic value)
{
      // Find the object based on it's name
      object target = this.Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == name);

      if (target != null)
      {
          // Find the correct property
          Type type = target.GetType();
          PropertyInfo prop = type.GetProperty(property);

          // Change the value of the property
          prop.SetValue(target, value);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "element" variable is the I'd of the control then using reflection:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = form1.Controls.Where(c => c.id == element).FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperty(property,
                            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
    if (propertyInfo != null)
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Equals(value.GetType()))
            propertyInfo.SetValue(control, value, null);
        else
            throw new Exception("Property DataType mismatch, expecting a " +
                                propertyInfo.PropertyType.ToString() + " and got a " +
                                value.GetType().ToString());
    }
}
```